# Get channel then create invite

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if (command === 'guilds') {
    if (message.author.id === ownerID) {
        let guilding = client.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "pain-logs")
        if (!guild.me.hasPermission("CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE")) {
            return message.channel.send(
                'I cannot Create Invites for ${guild.me.name}.'
            );
        }
        if (!guild.me.hasPermission("VIEW_CHANNEL")) {
            return message.channel.send(
                'I Cannot View Channels In ${guild.me.name}'
            );
        }
        guilding.createInvite().then(inv => console.log('${guild.name} | ${inv.url}', message.channel.send('${guild.name} | ${inv.url}')))
    }
}
```

error:

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined'
```

So I'm trying to find the channel (pain logs) then once it finds the channel it will create an invite to the channel but I keep getting that error

Comment: well, `client` object has `guilds` (notice the 's' at the end) not `guild`. check [the docs here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.guild` does not exist, `client.guilds` does exist, so if you want to get a specific channel from a specific guild you will have to do:

```js
//or some other way of getting it like `.get(id)`
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.name === "name");
if(!guild || !guild.available) return message.channel.send("Can't find guild");
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "pain-logs");
```

If you don't have any other servers the bot is in or you don't care which server it comes from you can use `client.channels`

```js
//might need to fetch it if it's not in the cache
const channel = client.channels.find(c => c.name === "pain-logs");
```

After that just check if the channel is viewable and create it

```js
if(!channel) return message.channel.send("No channel found");
if(!channel.viewable) return message.channel.send("Can't view the channel");
channel.createInvite()
.then(inv => {
  //guild.name will only work if you used the first method
  console.log(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`);
  message.channel.send(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    message.channel.send("Don't have permission");
});
```